# Determining kernel and image of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Problem:** Which of the following maps are linear? Determine the kernel and the image of the linear maps and check the dimension theorem. Which maps are isomorphisms?

1) $L_1: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto 2x + 1$

2) $L_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (x,y) \mapsto x+y$

3) $L_3: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3: (x,y) \mapsto (\sin x, 7y, xy)$

**Attempt at solution:** 1) We have that $L_1(x+y) = 2(x+y) + 1$ and $L_1(x) + L_1(y) = (2x+1) + (2y+1)$. So $L_1(x+y) \neq L_1(x) + L_1(y)$, and thus this map is not linear.

2) $L_2(x+x', y+y') = (x+x') + (y+y')$ and $L_2(x,y) + L_2(x',y') = (x+y)+(x'+y')$. Furthermore, $L_2(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda x + \lambda y$ and $ \lambda L_2 (x,y) = \lambda (x+y)$. So this map is linear.

Then for the kernel, all elements of the form $(x,-x)$ will satisfy $L_2(v) = 0$. But I'm not sure how to determine the dimension of this. Is it just all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? Moreover, I think the image of $L_2$ is just $\mathbb{R}$.

3) $L_3(x+x', y+y') = [\sin(x+x'), 7(y+y'), (x+x')(y+y')]$ and $L_3(x,y) + L_3(x',y') = (\sin(x), 7y , xy) + (\sin(x'), 7y', x'y')$. Since they are not equal, this is not a linear map.

Can someone tell me if my reasoning is correct? Also, how does one usually find the kernel and the image, as in the second linear map ?

Comment: (1) and (3) look good. For (2), the kernel is the set of all elements of the form $(x,-x)$, i.e. the space spanned by $(1,-1)$, and so the dimension is 1. For the image, given $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $L_2(x,0)=x$ and so $x$ is in the image. Therefore, the image is $\mathbb{R}$, which also has dimension 1.

Comment: Note that an isomorphism is a surjective (equivalently injective) linear map. Since the kernel of $L_2$ is not just $0_v$, is it not surjective and consequently not an isomorphism.

Comment: I see, thanks. So a linear map is an isomorphism when the kernel has zero dimension, and when it is also surjective?

Comment: @Kamil a linear map is an iso if it is injective (ie, its kernel is zero, ie, the dimension of its kernel is zero) and surjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

$L_1(0) = 1 \neq 0$, so $L_1$ is not linear.

2)

$$\begin{split} L_2((x,y)+(x',y')) &= L_2(x+x',y+y')\\ &= (x+x')+(y+y') \\ &= (x+y)+(x'+y')\\ &= L_2(x,y)+L_2(x',y')\end{split}$$

$$\begin{split} L_2(\lambda(x,y)) &= L_2(\lambda x,\lambda y)\\ &= \lambda x + \lambda y\\ &= \lambda(x+y)\\ &= \lambda L_2(x,y)\end{split}$$

So $L_2$ is linear.

Note that here an isomorphism means linear and bijective.

Since $Ker(L_2)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x+y=0\} = \{(x,-x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\} = \langle (1,-1) \rangle \neq \{(0,0)\}$, $L_2$ is not injective and then $L_2$ is not an isomorphism.

Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x=x+0=L_2(x,0)$, so $L_2$ is surjective and $Im(L_2)=\mathbb{R}$.

$dim(\mathbb{R}^2)=dim(KerL_2)+dim(ImL_2)$, so $dim(\mathbb{R}^2)=dim(\langle (1,-1) \rangle)+dim(\mathbb{R})$, so $2=1+1$, which is correct.

3)

I think you can do it by yourself now. You can suspect that $L_3$ is not linear because of the **sin**us or the $xy$, like for $L_1$, where the $+1$ is also suspicious.